# Is it possible to suppress NAnt's exec task's "[exec]" console output prefix

Tags: nant, teamcity, exec

I'm trying to integrate Robot Framework (an acceptance testing framework) with TeamCity. In order to do this it needs to send messages to the console output which TeamCity will then read and return realtime test progress/results. I'm doing this by calling the command line to run the tests with a simple exec task. Everything seemed to be working other than I was only getting the results at the end of the run and not on the fly.

After a bit of struggling with NAnt I swapped to using MSBuild and everything worked first time.

I have what I need now, but for completeness I'd like to find out why I couldn't get it working with NAnt. As far as I can tell the issue is that NAnt is prefixing all console output with [exec]. Is it possible to suppress this?

Comment: Great question! I have this exact same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the console output is configurable.

NAnt is open source: you could fork your own copy and/or submit a feature patch.